# Google map search autocomplete wont work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsp

I tried several codes but the dropdown suggestion from google wont show , i just want simple search autocomplete [Sample code/design that i want](http://jon.kim/how-to-add-google-maps-autocomplete-search-box/)

I dont think there is a problem with my api key since the map is showing, everything is working but the autocomplete dropdown search for places wont show, when i tried to put a button beside the search button it can return values.

```js
   
            function init() {
                var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>www.W3docs.com</title>
        <style>
            input {
                height: 30px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid rgb(186, 178, 178);
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #EFEFEF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        <label for="locationTextField">Location</label>
        <input id="locationTextField" type="text" size="50">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
     
    </body>
       

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine. The issue is on your API link. You have to specify your own key or else you won't have permission to use the library.

You can use:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

... but you will get warning that your key is not set.

Here's an example of this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEqAwg

To get a **free** api key, go to Google Developer site and click on **Get a Key**:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: i did specify my own key

Comment: I've done a Codepen on my answer. Is your code much different than that?

Comment: hmm then the issue might be something else, care to share your code on a jsbin/codepen?

Comment: @jpedroribeiro I think in your codepen you are not using the key. If you dont use the key autocomplete works but throw a warning NoApiKeys but with wrong key it will not work

Comment: hmm added the snippet, it is working there but in my program it does not... is there any compatibility issues with tomcat??

Comment: @Deep, yes my codepen was to illustrate exactly this situation.
SCS, ah, there you go! Hope it all works fine now.